# LaTeX figure problems

Tags: graphics, floats, jpeg

I want to include a `jpg` to a LaTeX document, which I have done many times. Normally, I use put it in a figure environment, the code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{myfig.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

When I try compiling this the document compiles, but no figure shows up. If I do not wrap the `\includegraphics` in a figure environment then the pdf compiles with the image. I want the `figure` environment, because I want to add captions/labels.

I can't figure out why this method does not work for this document, when it worked fine for other documents that I have made. The `jpg` is saved in the same directory as my `tex` file, so that is not the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex`? That is a requirement in order to include JPG files.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You shouldn't use an extension in the argument of `\includegraphics`, but that should not cause the issue. Can you edit in the `.log` file you get, in particular any warnings or errors?

Comment: "no figure shows up" - are there any warnings/errors in the logfile?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you (or a package) have disabled `\clearpage` (`\let\clearpage\relax`).
Do not do this, because `\clearpage` is needed. Apart from starting a new page it also forces LaTeX to output all pending floats. Thus `\clearpage` is automatically called at the start of `\chapter` and at the end of the document, for instance.

Thus if the figure is not yet output, `\clearpage` is disabled, and `\end{document}` is reached, then the figure "vanishes" and is not set in the document.

Frank Mittelbach has explained `\include` [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108323/16967). If you do not want page breaks by `\include`, then use `\input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'center' environment.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{myfig.jpg}
\caption{Blah blah blah...}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Your figure should now show up!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: instead of the `center` environment use `\centering`. It dowsn't add additional vertical space, what `\caption` already does.

Comment: The `center` environment is not recommended for images, see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651) for an explanation.