# toc not build correctly when using include

Tags: table-of-contents, include

I have a project with lots of large files that is not working correctly. It is to large to bugfix here, but perhaps I would know were to look If I learn the cause of some odd behavior in a simpler piece of code.

I have two files, `a.tex` and `b.tex`
b.tex gets included in `a.tex` but the `\clearpage` is annoying and therefore 'relaxed'.

`a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{import} 
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\include{b}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

`b.tex` (the `vspace` is to replace the effect of a large amount of text)

```
\section{Scalarfields}
\subsection{Child 1}
Test
\subsection{Child 2}
Test
\vspace{900pt}
\subsubsection{Childchild}
```

Now for some reason the Childchild `subsubsection` is not showing op in my `toc`. Any of you have a clue as to why not? I am using MikTeX with all packages installed and updated (a few days ago).

*Edit:*
I heard a lot of comments saying the `\include` command needs the `\clearpage`, so relaxing it is a bad idea. If so I should indeed consider using `\input`. Is there is no way to have the separate aux files and something like the `\includeonly` for the input command? (didn't think so) Because that's the reason I am using `\include` …

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show subsections and subsubsections in TOC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsections-and-subsubsections-in-toc)

Comment: Your \let\clearpage\relax does nothing in this contents.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I don't think so, I tried fiddling with the counters and the problems is gone when I replace the include with the actual content of b.tex. Seems like a different situation to me.

It does something, when it is not there there is a \newpage 'effect' right after the toc (because the include command uses \clearpage)
The 'problem' is gone when ge \let\clearpage\relax part is removed, so I think it is relevant.

Comment: `\let\clearpage\relax\tableofcontents\include{b}` is a _really_ bad idea. `\clearpage` is an essential part of the definition of `\include`.

Comment: Doing `\let\clearpage\relax` is simply wrong: `\include` needs it for its workings. Use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel it does do _something_ it breaks `\include`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Indeed. Without this flaw it works with tocdepth.

Comment: Related to the `\clearpage` problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108268/redefining-include

Comment: Why do you need the `b.aux` file?

Comment: @egreg because the I was trying to understand my mistake and the symptoms of the 'illness' disappeared without the include

Comment: @egreg O, u said .aux, not .tex ... fail

Well, I guess I do not need the .aux file itself, I just like the idea that the files are evaluated separately (because they are large)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to input another file without a forced page break use

```
\input{b}
```

Redefining `\clearpage` to `\relax` is inherantly dangerous (it would be quite likely to make latex never terminate) but in particular here it breaks the `\include` mechanism completely.

Comment: ok, so I'd either learn to live with the pagebreak, or use \input and forget about the benefits of \include?

Comment: @Fictional yes.

Comment: I read somewhere about that the \include* from the newclude package does not use a \clearpage. It seems however like a backwards com­pat­i­bility thingy. Would it we 'wise' at all to use this package?

Comment: @Fictional sorry can't comment on packages I haven't seen:-)

Comment: @Fictional The package is not developed since November 1999 (and the author says it's under development). Maybe it works, maybe not. But I doubt that a `scrartcl` document benefits from `\include`.

Comment: @egreg Why whould a scrartcl not benefit from \includes then?

Comment: This work with 1 input file, for me it doesn't work with 2 or more input files. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: @Surb don't ask a new question on a comment on an ancient answer, impossible to say. `\input` is more or less transparent, tex just acts as if the input text had been copied to that place. If it doesn't work, make a small example that shows the problem and ask a new question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for asking new question in comment and thanks replying. While preparing the minimal example I found where was the mistake. There was a \stop in one of my files.

Comment: @Surb no harm done:-)