# Undefined reference using a0poster (\include Vs. \input)

Tags: cross-referencing, input, include

I have an `a0poster` document (see below an example) which is not loading the cross-references, although `bibtex` is working fine and compiling the references.

I write the main text into a different `tex` file and include it into the main tex file (both can be found below).

If the file `text.tex` is included with `\include`, the cross-referencing fails. If
it is included using `\input`, everything works fine. Why?

PS: The file `main.tex` below has lots of `\usepackages` and some definitions required by the `a0poster` class.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[portrait]{a0poster}

\RequirePackage{amssymb,amsthm,array}
\RequirePackage[reqno]{amsmath}

% revtex
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{doi}%<----------
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Insert font types as \LARGE or \color
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}%I took out the package cite
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\renewcommand\familydefault{cmss}

% Switch off page numbers on a poster, obviously, and section numbers too.
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % underline \uline
\usepackage{pifont} % inclui suporte a simbolos \ding no texto
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % inclui outros simbolos

% These colours are tried and tested for titles and headers. Don't
% over use color!
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.5}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.9,0.0,0.1}

% put text on the top of the image
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

% see documentation for a0poster class for the size options here
\newcommand{\Textsize}{\large}
\newcommand{\IntroTextsize}{\large}
\newcommand{\Abstractsize}{\normalsize}
\newcommand{\TReferences}{\scriptsize}
\def\Head#1{\noindent\hbox to \hsize{\hfil{\Huge\color{DarkBlue} #1}}\bigskip}
\def\TAuthors#1{\noindent{\huge\color{DarkBlue} #1}\smallskip}
\def\TAddress#1{\noindent{\Large\color{DarkBlue} #1}\smallskip}
\def\LHead#1{\noindent{\Huge\color{DarkBlue} #1}\smallskip}
\def\Subhead#1{\noindent{\Large\color{DarkBlue} #1}}
\def\Title#1{\noindent{\VERYHuge\color{Red} #1}}

\TPGrid[20mm,20mm]{15}{25}  % 3 - 1 - 7 - 1 - 3 Columns

% Mess with these as you like
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0.5\baselineskip

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\include{text} %%%%% gives the undefined reference error

\input{text} %%%%% loads the text with correct cross-referencing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



    \begin{textblock}{7}(7.8,21.6)
\begin{multicols}{2}
\TReferences
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1-custom}
\bibliography{referencias}
\end{multicols}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

**text.tex**

```
\begin{textblock}{7}(0.25,5.8)

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:myEqn1}
f(x) = a + bx
\end{equation}

eq \eqref{eq:myEqn1} is a straight line! %%%% display '??' undefined reference

\end{textblock}
```

Comment: Using `\include` for a poster is wrong: it wants (and needs) to issue a page break that can't happen, so everything goes awry. Use `\input` and live happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\include` with this class; the `\include` mechanism *requires* a page break, which can't be performed in a poster. Actually `a0poster` (or a package input by it) redefines `\clearpage` not to really issue a page break.

Since `\include` doesn't see the necessary page break, the label can't be properly written in the secondary `.aux` file, so the result is that the label is lost. Indeed the code

```
\newlabel{eq:myEqn1}{{1}{1}{}{equation.0.1}{}}
```

appears in the `.log` file, which means that the `.aux` file isn't correctly open when `\label` is executed.

See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) and especially [Redefining \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108268/redefining-include) for reference.