# reftex: include from `tex/`

Tags: emacs, import, reftex

In order to keep doc dir clean, I keep a master file in the top level of the doc, and other files in folders:

```
.
├── bib
│   └── refs.bib
├── img
│   ├── img1.png
│   └── img2.png
├── tex
│   ├── part1.tex
│   ├── part2.tex
│   └── part3.tex
├── tmp
└── master.tex
```

I import tex files from tex with:

```
% include from tex/
\usepackage{import}
\def\includeFromTex#1 {\subimport{tex/}{#1.tex}\include{#1}}
```

Example usage:

```
\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax % tweak that stops include from starting with newpage
\includeFromTex{10_-_calc}
\includeFromTex{20_-_disc}
\includeFromTex{30_-_app}
\endgroup
```

And every file under `tex/` starts with:

```
% -*- TeX-master: "../master.tex" -*-
```

This works fine with tex, but breaks reftex ability to build toc, and reference things. Is it possible to notify reftex that I keep tex files under `tex/`?

**Edit**:

Since I can't tweak reftex to do that, I moved texs to the doc dir:

```
.
├── bib
│   └── refs.bib
├── img
│   ├── img1.png
│   └── img2.png
├── tmp
├── 10_-_part1.tex
├── 20_-_part2.tex
├── 30_-_part3.tex
└── master.tex
```

Now I'm using plain `\input{}` for files and everything works (latex and reftex).

(BTW if one numbers the parts, the the master file will always be the last one. In this case it is possible to make it `TeX-master` automatically:

```
% -*- eval: (setq TeX-master (car (last (directory-files default-directory nil ".*\\.tex$")))) -*-
```

one should put this line at the top of child tex files)

Comment: why use a delimited argument? also why not simply `\include{tex/part1}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: include starts each file with a new page. Normally I don't need that. That's why I'm using `import` instead of `include`.

Comment: @Adobe, the `reftex` parser only looks at `\include` and `\input`, so it might simply be easier to store the normal value of `\include` in a macro via `\let\oldinclude\include`, and then redefine `\include`. I've used that trick before to get around exactly this issue where I wanted a specialized input command, but also wanted `reftex` and `auctex` to be able to find and parse stuff.

Comment: oh in your example usage you are using `{10_-_calc}` with `{..}` so why define `\includeFromTex` with a delimited argument delimited by space? That allows `\includeFromTex 10_-_calc` but that's not really normal latex syntax and you don't use it anyway. But as it is if you were to use `\includeFromTex{10_-_calc}%` things would go very wrong as the end of line is required.

Comment: `\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax % tweak that stops include from starting with newpage` That is not a tweak it breaks the include system totally and you will get corrupted aux files and incorrect numbering. There is an answer about that on site somewhere.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108268/redefining-include

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: do you mean I should use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`?

Comment: @Adobe you can use `\def` if you must but `\def\foo#1 {....}` defines the argument of `\foo` not to be the next `{}` group but to be everything up to the next space. `\def\foo#1{....}` would be the thing to use to define a command as `\newcommand` would define it with an argument delimited by `{}`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the `\includeonly` system and do not want your included files to start on a new page just use

```
\input{tex/10_-_calc}
\input{tex/20_-_disc}
\input{tex/30_-_app}
```

As mentioned in comments

```
\def\includeFromTex#1 {..
```

defines `\includeFromTex` to take as argument everything up to the next space (or end of line) so in your example use the `{}` were being ignored and the end of line white space was *required*.

The redefinition of `\clearpage` to `\relax` would certainly break the `\include` mechanism and can result in data being lost or written to the wrong aux file.

reftex working showing the section picked up in the input file:

[image]

Comment: But using `input` one can't store tex files under `tex/`. Actually the problem is not with latex: I succedded in making latex aware that files are under `tex/`, but with emacs's reftex.

Comment: @Adobe of course you can, why ever not?

Comment: @Adobe reftex seems to understand `\input{tex/10_-_calc}` perfectly well?

Comment: Nope: http://i.imgur.com/cXEZMET.png (the apper window should actually produce ToC)

Comment: @Adobe something strange about your emacs setup then, I just tried reftex-toc on a sample file and the toc shows entries in the file input from a subdirectory. I added an image to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Hmm: the variable `reftex-include-file-commands` might also be useful, it lists the macro names takes to be including other docs.

Comment: One can't teach `reftex-include-file-commands` to search for files in particular directory.

Comment: No you are right. It was more a reference to where to add more `\include` like macro names. I think you should write the people on the `auctex` mailing list. They are quite helpful. It is probably not them who maintain `reftex` but they know quite a lot about how it works.