# Prevent include another file from making a new page

Tags: formatting, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I want to have main project file `main.tex` and import other sections in it. I used to put everything in one file but I am trying now to use elegant way using either `include` or `input` commands. I chose `include` because it does not produce pdf of sections (Only I want `main.tex` is the one is compiled and then pdf is generated from it). I do the following:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEE_format/IEEEtran}

% Paper Title goes here
\title{Later \vspace{-0.5cm} }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\include{sections/Intro}
\include{sections/Background}
\include{sections/Problem_statement}


\end{document}
```

However, every section goes to a new page! how can I avoid that (i.e.,  every section follows the previous one)? The command `input` does that but it generates pdf of each section which I don't want that.

Thank you

Comment: \input{sections/file}

Comment: Check if this post covers your needs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include. If so, it is a duplicate

Comment: `\input` does not generate a pdf of each section. It just tells LaTeX to treat the place where you use it as if the contents of the specified file were there.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it sounds like what you're looking for is `\inputonly`, but that, unfortunately. doesn't exist.  the best suggestion i can offer is to use `\input` and comment out temporarily any sections you won't want to look at in the current processing cycle.

Comment: this question sounds like a better "duplicate": [Redefining \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108268/579)